# Identifying the most purchased combination of items in SQL

Tags: sql

First of all, I hope everyone's staying safe out there. 
So here's my question. 
Currently I'm trying to figure out how I can identify the most purchased combination of items. 
Most purchased combination of items must appear at the top (descending order is crucial).

Let's say I have a sales table that looks like this:

```
Cust_ID   Item_ID
100       A
100       A
100       B
100       C
200       A
200       C
200       C
300       B
400       A
400       B
```

and the expected output looks something like this:

```
Comb_of_Item   Count_of_Cust
A, B           10
A, C           7
B, C           4
A, B, C        2
```

Note that Customer 100 had purchased item "A" twice, which for the purpose of this exercise will be ignored (dups to be removed). 
This means that Customer 100 would be counted as "A, B, C" NOT "A, A, B, C" 
Any help/suggestion would be much appreciated.

Many thanks advance!

Comment: Does the expected result really match the given sample data? Make it easy to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: You say that you want "the most purchased combination of items."  That suggests one combination.  Yet your results show multiple combinations.

Comment: Sorry guys a newbie here. Just wanted to get some guidelines. That's all. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this can be modify into a better query but right now this will get the job done.

```
select combo_of_item,count(combo_of_item) Count_of_Cust from (
select Cust_ID ,string_agg(Item_ID,',') combo_of_item  from (
select distinct * from [table] ) a
group by Cust_ID) b
group by Combo_of_item
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8a100943dbb497b05c75141b18271760)

btw since OP didn't provide dbms, `string_egg` might have to alter depends on which db OP is currently using.